# Zypper: relocation error

Tags: system-installation

"Zypper: relocation error: zypper: symbol _ZN4zypp5CpeId11NoThrowType13lastMalformedE, version ZYPP_plain not defined in file libzypp.so.1503 with link time reference"

Appear right after I installed it. Anytime I use the word `zypper` in the console it appears.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Please, use copy and paste instead of pictures to show errors

Comment: May I ask, Why do you need zypper?

Comment: Zypper should be used on OpenSUSE systems. Not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zypper isn't meant to be used on a debian system, such as Ubuntu.